# What probe received the most gravitational assists?

Tags: deep-space, probe, gravity-assist

Often when launching deep-space probes, scientists will "loop" them around planets, "stealing" some of the planet's momentum and transferring it to the probe - giving the probe a huge speed boost.

I've heard of multiple assists being chained together, for example Jupiter, then Saturn, then flying off at enormous speed out of the solar system.

It seems that getting more and more of these assists would be beneficial to the probe's mission. Which probe that we have launched has received the most gravitational assists?

Comment: Largest number, or largest total delta-vee?

Comment: @gerrit Largest total number of assists.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you only count planets, then I believe it's [MESSENGER](http://messenger.jhuapl.edu/the_mission/trajectory.html) at six.

Though your question was explicitly: "Which probe that we have launched has received the most gravitational assists?"  The winner there is [Cassini](http://saturn.jpl.nasa.gov/mission/flybys/), hands down.  It is on Titan flyby number <s>93</s> 125, so far.  And it's flown by other moons of Saturn.  Plus the four planetary flybys on the way to Saturn.

Comment: Wondering what the final update would be, I decided to ask [If Cassini's final flyby of Saturn's moon Titan is the 127th Titan flyby, why is it called “T-126”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31466/12102)

Comment: Note: Parker Solar Probe, assuming it continues to operate, will beat MESSENGER with seven Venus flybys.

Comment: Did/will Parker get an assist at Earth as well?

Comment: Nope...........